# Compile Phonegap Project on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

Recently, not without some headache, I installed iphone-gcc and all required headers on my jailbroken iPod Touch (like [this](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-install-perl-theos-and-iphone.html)). Because neither do I have a Mac nor do I know Objective-C, I began looking for alternative solutions for app development.

So, is it possible to compile a Phonegap project directly on the iDevice? In other words, I need to "convert" a web app in Phonegap format into an iOS application, like it is done in XCode.

***P.S.*** The SDK I have installed is of version 3.2

***Progress Report:*** Following the suggestion by user [hatunike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004044/hatunike) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896608/can-phonegap-be-used-in-apps-built-with-theos)) I tried to link the PhoneGap framework into a dummy project on my iPod to see if it works. It does not. Looks like PhoneGap uses some features that were only introduced in iOS 4. The developers [say](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/blob/0.9.6/README.md) it is possible to compile a PhoneGap application for an older iOS by weak-linking UIKit, AVFoundation and CoreMedia. Problem is, weak-linking those frameworks requires a newer iOS SDK than the target SDK.

Comment: Well -- PhoneGap uses the native toolchain/libraries, so, as it's an Xcode project, you'll have to convert it to a barebones, toolchain-compatible format. For this, you'll certainly need some Objective-C experience and it's a rather sophisticated kind of work, so I suggest you to take up regular, native iOS development instead. It's not that hard as you might imagine at first, and it's worth it. There' much more functionality in the system which PhoneGap cannot provide (for example, MobileSubstrate, etc...)

Comment: In that case, is there some sort of GUI builder for Windows that I can use? I don't like the idea of defining the interface in source files.

Comment: Not really. (btw how do you want to program without writing source?)

Comment: I've got no problem with writing source. It's just that I don't like designing user interfaces by writing text files. It's more natural to use visual design tools.

Comment: OK, I understand, it may be your personal preference, but unortunately there are no known Windows GUI SDKs which would support iOS

Comment: @H2CO3, I found one of your posts on the [XSellize forums](http://xsellize.com/topic/111034-toolchain-for-ios-42/) (if it really is you). I didn't quite understand the process, so maybe you can help me compile the toolchain for version 4.3 of the iOS SDK.

Comment: Yeah it's me :) You may want to email me, I could explain it to you in detail.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://build.phonegap.com/

you still need to have a developer key from Apple but your jailbroken iPod should allow you to put the built file on your device. its free for 1 private app.